# jQuery .each() for DOM objects not running; what am I missing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building an Html Partial for navigation in part of an MVC solution. All of the CSS, HTML, and JavaScript are contained in the partial. I would like to add the CSS class "current" to the current page within the navigation by running the navigation steps through a jQuery .each() function, but the function never executes (the debugger hits it and jumps over it). What could I be doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

```js
var myURL = 'https://example.com/path/sftpaccount'; 
var arrURL = myURL.split('/');
// I was originally using window.location.pathname instead of the full URL
var thisView = arrURL[arrURL.length - 1].toLowerCase();
console.log(thisView);
console.log($('.navStep').length);
$('.navStep').each(function() {
  if (thisView == $(this).data('viewName').toLowerCase()) {
    $(this).addClass('current');
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('current');
  }
})
```

```css
.current { text-decoration: underline;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row navRow">
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center navStep" data-viewName="sftpaccount" onclick="window.location = '/Integration/SftpAccount';">
    <div class="stepFirst">Step 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center navStep" data-viewName="sftp_columnmapping" onclick="window.location = '/Integration/Sftp_ColumnMapping';">
    <div class="step">Step 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center navStep" data-viewName="sftp_documentmapping" onclick="window.location = '/Integration/Sftp_DocumentMapping';">
    <div class="step">Step 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center navStep" data-viewName="sftp_usermapping" onclick="window.location = '/Integration/Sftp_UserMapping';">
    <div class="stepLast">Step 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *"the debugger hits it and jumps over it"* - Log the value of `$('.navStep')` to the console just before calling `.each()` on it.  Are any matching elements found?  If not then when the code runs these elements don't exist.

Comment: are you trying to run it before the DOM loads?

Comment: `if (thisView == $(element).data('viewname')) {` use lowercase data attributes always

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `toLowerCase()` on the result of `.data()`. You have to use a lowercase name: `viewname` instead of `viewName`. HTML attributes are case-insensitive, so `data-viewName` is treated as `data-viewname`

Comment: But the error that comes from doing that proves that it *is* going into `.each()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use lowercase for the data attribute name when retrieving the value.

```js
if (thisView == $(element).data('viewname'))
```

You should always use lowercase in data attributes to avoid such issues.

Comment: [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/g3d9p7yn/)

Comment: That is a close vote and a  comment, not an answer

Comment: This fixes a different problem than the one in the question.